# Augmenting the classpath of legacy OSGi bundles in Eclipse Equinox

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, equinox

We are trying to migrate an existing Eclipse IDE Product from Java 8 to Java 11.

Everything worked fine with our own code; but, unfortunately, the product also includes some (quite old) bundles from a third party. Those bundles have been built and are working under Java 8 and use `javax.xml.bind` (JAXB) and we don't have access to the source code, so we cannot rebuild them for Java 11.

Now the problem is that those bundles assume that `javax.xml.bind` is on the (Java Runtime Library) classpath (which was correct for Java 8), so they don't have an `Import-Package` for JAXB in their manifests. When executed in our new Java 11 product, of course, this ends up in `NoClassDefFoundException`s for the JAXB classes.

My research so far has ended up in two possibilities to solve this:

1. Add JAXB to the Java Classpath by providing it as a module and add a corresponding `--add-modules` argument as VM argument in the `eclipse.ini`.
2. For each legacy bundle, create a fragment with additional `Import-Package` headers to add the JAXB import to each of the affected bundles.

The first solution does not work well for us, because our own bundles already use an `Import-Package` header in the manifest to make use of JAXB which is available in our target platform as an OSGi bundle. If we added a JAXB module to Java, we would end up with problems that classes/packages are available in two modules (the unnamed one from the OSGi bundle, and the JAXB that we added via command line).

The second solution works, but the disadvantage is that we need to create *N* fragments for *N* legacy bundles, which adds quite some clutter to our codebase.

So my question is: Is there any other mechanism in Equinox that I can use to make some packages (JAXB) known to the BundleClassloader of certain bundles (our legacy bundles) **without** having to modify or rebuild these legacy bundles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching around the keywords given in [BJ Hargrave's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448551/bj-hargrave) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71677272/2239897), we ended up finding [this blog entry on vogella by Dirk Fauth](http://blog.vogella.com/2021/03/08/eclipse-rcp-java-11-jaxb/). Variant 3 in that article describes the way we successfully applied.

In short,

- create a fragment to `system.bundle` and set it to be a `framework` extension
- put the libraries you need on the classpath in that fragment (or configure the POM to let Maven do it for you)
- export the packages you need exported

`MANIFEST.MF` of the fragment (excerpt):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: JAXB framework extension
Bundle-SymbolicName: net.winklerweb.jaxbfix
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Fragment-Host: system.bundle; extension:=framework
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-11
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar,
 lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar,
 lib/jaxb-impl-2.2_1.jar,
 .
Export-Package: com.sun.istack,
 com.sun.istack.localization,
 com.sun.istack.logging,
```

`pom.xml` of the fragment (excerpt):

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>net.winklerweb</groupId>
<artifactId>net.winklerweb.jaxbfix</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
                        <includeArtifactIds>jakarta.activation-api,jakarta.xml.bind-api,jaxb-impl</includeArtifactIds>
                        <failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>false</failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>
                        <silent>false</silent>
                        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute>
                                        <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                        <runOnConfiguration>true</runOnConfiguration>
                                    </execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.bundles</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2_1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Finally, a few useful links explaining OSGi/Equinox class loading which I have come across during my research:

- https://moi.vonos.net/java/osgi-classloaders/
- http://www.martinlippert.org/events/WJAX2008-ClassloadingTypeVisibilityOSGi.pdf
- https://www.jfokus.se/jfokus09/slides/salong4/OSGiClassloading.pdf

Comment: Do you use Tycho build? In my case, Tycho cannot find packages contained in the fragment

Comment: My question and answer were more related to runtime than to build time. We had the problem that I have solved with this answer that we include legacy bundles that we don’t have control of to the built product. Any new bundle we have control of and that we are building ourselves don’t use this fragment but an actual `Require-Bundle: javax.xml.bind` to use JAXB as an OSGi bundle.

Answer (score 1):

The bundles should always have imported `javax.*` packages. Those bundles were always wrong.

Have you tried [boot delegation](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/8.0.0/framework.module.html#framework.module.parentdelegation) along with adding JAXB to the Java classpath?

`org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.bind.*`

If there is already a bootdelegation value in place, you will need to add `javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.bind.*` to the existing value.

Since you also have bundles which import the `javax.xml.bind` packages, you will also need to make sure the system bundle exports them. So you will need to configure `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` property with all the JAXB packages including versions if necessary for your imports.

`org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=javax.xml.bind;version=1.2.3, ...`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Although the boot delegation did not completely fit because the required classes were not available at JRE level for us (because we didn't want to add the JAXB module), the keywords and pointers led me into searching for the right keywords that led me to a working solution - see my answer on a description what we ended up doing.